# react-google-chart timeline, allowHtml doesn't work - renders at text

Tags: reactjs, react-google-charts

I'm trying to add the html tag to the label of Timeline from react-google-chart and I cannot figure out why it doesn't work. The HTML is rendered as text.

```
'use client'
import {Chart} from "react-google-charts"
import {ensureLeadingSlash} from "next/dist/shared/lib/page-path/ensure-leading-slash";

export default function Timeline({schedule}) {
    const columns = [
        { type: 'string', id: 'Key' },
        { type: 'string', id: 'Value' },
        { type: 'date', id: 'Start' },
        { type: 'date', id: 'End'}
    ]

    // const rows = [];

    const chartEvents = [
        {
            eventName: "ready",
            callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
                const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "select", e => {
                    let { row, column }  = chart.getSelection()[0];
                    console.log(rows[row][0]);
                });
            }
        }
    ];

    const rows = [
      ['Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>', 32, new Date("2023-01-01"), new Date("2023-02-01")],
      ["Libby", 41, new Date("2023-04-01"), new Date("2023-06-01")],
      ["Joe", 22, new Date("2023-05-01"), new Date("2023-07-01")],
      ["Maria", 42, new Date("2023-01-01"), new Date("2023-03-01")],
      ["Kate", 36, new Date("2023-07-01"), new Date("2023-08-01")],
      ["Max", 67, new Date("2023-06-01"), new Date("2023-09-01")],
      ["Miranda", 19, new Date("2023-09-01"), new Date("2023-10-01")],
      ["Karen", 25, new Date("2023-02-01"), new Date("2023-03-01")]
    ];


    const data = [columns, ...rows]

    return <Chart
        chartType="Timeline"
        data={data}
        width="100%"
        height="400px"
        chartEvents={chartEvents}
        options={{
            allowHtml: true
          }}
    />;

}
```

[image]